# Getting NServiceBus Subscriptions from RavenDB

Tags: json.net, ravendb, nservicebus

Has anyone tried (and succeeded) to get subscriptions out of RavenDB with the Raven DB .Net client?

Having some Json serialisation issues that when the following runs, it throws with a

*"Error converting value "Subscriber.Messages.Events.MyEvent, Version=1.0.0.0" to type 'NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.MessageType'.* message

The code is simple :

```
            var documentStore = new DocumentStore
            {
                Url = "http://localhost:8080/",
                DefaultDatabase = "publisher",
            };

            documentStore.Initialize();

            using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
            {

                return session.Query<NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.Raven.Subscription>("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName").ToArray();
            }
```

It's definitely a serialisation issue as the retrieval works. As it does using the alternative below:

```
session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Subscription>("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName").QueryResult.Results[0]
```

In the RaveDB studio I can see the following document in the publisher database.

```
{
  "MessageType": "Subscriber.Messages.Events.MyEvent, Version=1.0.0.0",
  "Clients": [
    {
      "Queue": "samplesubscriber",
      "Machine": "myDesktopHere"
    }
  ]
}
```

Error converting value "Subscriber.Messages.Events.MyEvent, Version=1.0.0.0" to type 'NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.MessageType'.

Anyone have a clue why the serialization fails?

I'm using NServiveBus.Host 4.2, Raven-DB client 1.0.616, and Newtonsoft.json 4.0.5.

Incidentally I've pulled up the types using dotpeek and created local versions. I created my own subcription, MessageType, MessageTypeConvertor from the NSB dll's. I then managed to deserialise the strings without issue. Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

As per suggestions the advance Lucene query does a great job of retrieving the results. But then deserialization fails. For example, search results are returned in the first line, but fail to deserlize in the return statement. I've pulled up a local version of the Subscription type from the NSB dll's, and implemented the type converter, again pulled up from the NSB libraries, and using those in place of NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.Raven.Subscription works fine. Inevitably, that's not a stable choice.

```
var searchResults = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.Raven.Subscription>("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName").WhereEquals("Tag", "Subscription").QueryResult.Results;

return searchResults.Select(subscriptionJsonObject => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.Raven.Subscription>(subscriptionJsonObject.ToString())).ToList();
```

Any further thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

When you query with this form:

```cs
session.Query<Entity>("IndexName")
```

You are asking for *all* items of that index to be returned from the query, and then telling the RavenDB client to deserialize them *all* as the type you specified.

Normally, that works out quite well because a specific index would be built for the types you're working with.  For example, you would usually build your own index of subscriptions for a specific purpose, and query that:

```cs
session.Query<Subscription>("Subscriptions/ByWhatever")
```

or if you built the index from C#, you might like this syntax instead to avoid the string:

```cs
session.Query<Subscription, Subscriptions_ByWhatever>()
```

You could also just let Raven build an index for you automatically:

```cs
session.Query<Subscription>()
```

Since you used the built-in `Raven/DocumentsByEntityName` index, you are returning all documents in the database, not just those that are subscriptions.  Since only some can be deserialized as a `Subscription` type, the others are failing with serialization errors.

If you'd like to continue to use that index, you would need to filter it to just those of that type:

```cs
session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Subscription>("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName")
                .WhereEquals("Tag", "Subscriptions")
```

The `LuceneQuery` form is easier here, since you are filtering a field by its string name.

You could use a regular LINQ query, but you'd have to create a type that contains the `Tag` field, like this:

```cs
class RDBENIndexEntry
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}

...

session.Query<RDBENIndexEntry>("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName")
       .Where(x => x.Tag == "Subscriptions").OfType<Subscription>()
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, unfortunately that doesn't resolve the problem. As suggested I pulled back the results with the advanced query. That bit works, but the serilaization post retrieval fails. I'll edit the original with details.